# can someone help me fix this code(string)-java

Tags: java

I try to write a old maid. 
After dealing cards,and sorting, i have two parts of card,one is playerDeck, one is computerDeck. now the pairs need to be removed.but i was stuck at this stage.

for example(just an example )
playerDeck:
 'A♡', 'A♢', '8♡', '8♢', '8♠', 'Q♠', '2♠', '4♣', '7♢', '7♣', 'K♣', 'A♡', 'J♡', '9♣',  '3♢'

computerDeck:
'3♡','3♣', '10♡','10♠','10♣', '6♡',  'K♡','K♢', 'A♣', 'A♠', '4♢', '7♡','7♠'

```
    String q;
    String p;
    ArrayStringsTools AA=new ArrayStringsTools();//this is a class that i will use for removing item
    for(int i=0;i<playerDeck.length-1;i++){
        q=playerDeck[i];
        q=q.substring(0,1);//i try to find the first character 


        p=playerDeck[i+1];//after finding first character, i can compare them,and if they are same, then i can remove them
        p=p.substring(0,1);


        if(q==p){
            AA.removeItemByIndex(playerDeck,26,i);//this is the method that i used for removing same item,i will put this code below 
            AA.removeItemByIndex(playerDeck,26,i+1);//there are 51 cards in total,player has 26, computer has 25
        }

    }

public static int removeItemByIndex(String[] arrayOfStrings, int currentSize, int itemToRemove){//this is the method i used for removing item(first is the array of Deck, second is the size of Deck,third is the index of item to remove)

    if( arrayOfStrings == null || currentSize > arrayOfStrings.length) {
        System.out.println("ArrayStringsTools.removeItemByIndex: wrong call");
        return currentSize;
    }
    if( itemToRemove < 0 || itemToRemove >= currentSize ) {
        System.out.println("ArrayStringsTools.removeItem: item " 
            + itemToRemove + " out of bounds. Array Unchanged.");
        return currentSize;
    }

    int i;
    for( i = itemToRemove; i < currentSize-1; i++){
        arrayOfStrings[i] = arrayOfStrings[i+1];
    }
    arrayOfStrings[i]= null;
    return currentSize-1;
```

i think i wrote correctly, but it doesnt show any difference compared with the origin.
the result should be:
playerDeck: '8♠', 'Q♠', '2♠', '4♣', 'K♣', 'A♡', 'J♡', '9♣',  '3♢'
computerDeck:'10♣', '6♡',  '4♢'

or is there another way to do this,because when a pair removed,there are two empty spaces, so... I've been struggling for a long time......

Comment: What output your are expecting and what output you are getting ??

Comment: playerDeck: '8♠', 'Q♠', '2♠', '4♣', 'K♣', 'A♡', 'J♡', '9♣',  '3♢'
computerDeck:'10♣', '6♡',  '4♢'

Comment: Break your long lines into shorter ones. It is a pain to read very long lines of code, because if you scroll to see the end of a line, you lose sight of the rest of the program. A common limin is "no line longer than 80 characters"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the 1st character, change this line

```
 if (q == p) {
```

to

```
 if (q.charAt(0) == p.charAt(0)) {
```

Notice that `q == p` checks to see if the `q` and `p` refer to the *same string*, and do not look at the contents at all. If you want to compare full strings (or any other object that is not a char, an int, or so on) by content, you should use `equals`: `q.equals(p)` returns true only if both have the same content.

Comment: now it says'exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException' at test.main(test.java.52)   52th row is "p=p.substring(0,1);" whats wrong

Comment: `p` is `null` at that point. A `null` reference does not point to an actual object; and it is an error to try to call `substring(0,1)` on a null reference (since there is no actual object to receive the call). As to *why* `p` is null, you probably forgot to initialize its value. When declaring, say, an array of `String` as `String a[] = new String[10]`, all 10 `String` references in the array start out pointing to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two strings,you can use 'equals',like

```
if(q.equals(p)){//q==p if true,they are save in the same location-this may not be what you want,and in this code it will be false forever.

}
```

Comment: i just want to compare the first character

Comment: String is not primitive type,not like  char,you only can use equals to test strings for equality.

Comment: @Joe convert with toCharArray and then compare the first elements of each new array

Comment: @MarkYisri Why would you want to allocate a new char array just to check the first element?

Comment: @Silverclaw while I know it is a waste, it allows for more flexible code later on. Of course, the OP can always use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41825449/6754053).